# tesselate a model with vastly different sizes of triangles in a way trigangles have roughly the same size?

Tags: scripting

I have an issue that is the opposite of dynamic topology. In order to remap the details onto a lowpoly model, I need to remesh the model so that has roughly the same triangle size across the model. Is there a script that can analyze the mesh and tessellate it at places were the triangles are to large to a kind of normalized triangle size? Perferably with keeping an existing UV map ....

Comment: Maybe try a Remesh modifier then a Triangulate modifier ?

Comment: yeah, that works in general but has servere downsides, that I am looking for another way.

a.) in order to capture the details of the model, it needs to have at least Octree depth =9 or better 10 .... => gazzillion of polygons

b.) the UV map is crap and the maps need to be projected from original to remeshed model, which is also an awkward process.

A python script that tessellates all larger trigs with a too big area ... that would be perfect. It could keep the original UV mapping and would have way less polygons

Comment: Did you tried Dynotopo's "Details Flood Fill" operator once enabled "Constant Detail"? It will not keep the uv map though...

Comment: Making all faces roughly the same size without loss of detail will necessarily require the new triangles to be the size of the smallest one. (barring some needlessly dense flat section having the smallest tri)

Comment: thx, Detail Flood fill with constant details, does the trick. Looses the UV map, but that's OK as I can project to the new model